# Why my JSOn code error?

Tags: php, json, openldap

I tried to connecting JSON into my db to access the users list, but I got this error:

> Uncaught Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: [{gid:"7503",cn:"Marketing",}]
>       **Notice**:  Undefined variable: ldapcon in **C:\xampp\htdocs\site\resources\admin\getGroups.php** on line **38**

I guess, I  forgot to put comma inside it, can you please help me?

Comment: Validate the json with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: You did not forget to put a comma, there's one comma too much.

Comment: How did you get that broken JSON? You should use `json_encode()` in the PHP script, not try to create JSON by hand.

Comment: you right Barmar I am not using the json_encode, maybe I should change my code, @samlev, after I remove the comma, I got error protocol, I will add the protocol code (V3). Hope I am lucky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON requires the keys to be in double-quoted strings, and there can't be a trailing comma:

```
{"gid":"7503","cn":"Marketing"}
```

Comment: After trial and error, finally I got it. Thanks all :)